# Why this rendering artifacts happen?

Tags: html, css, cordova, phonegap

I'm developing simple mobile game for android using cordova. The game is the simple Hidden Object game where player has to find requested objects on the scene. One of my levels had very slow performance. More powerful devices worked fine. I've tried force GPU rendering using translateZ hack and got huge performance boost but, on low-end devices started wired rendering artifacts. [image]

This screenshot is from  Meizu U10. The background consists of 3 layers with position absolute, z-index 1,2,3. Objects to find (Cow, chicken etc) has same position absolute and z-index depends from background they are related to. If run game in browser on the same device, there is no artifacts and performance just great. Google did not give me any useful clues, so i will be very appreciate any guesses and tips.

Comment: is this a flat image? or svg?

Comment: It is png, two bottom layers have transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Using `SVG` can be an option you might need to consider, specifically inline SVGs.

> Using inline SVG is beneficial to the performance of a website because
>   it **eliminates the HTTP request needs to load in an image file**. Since
>   no file needs to download, this results in smaller loading times for a
>   page. This makes your website appear faster to visitors, improving the
>   user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider using a webGL rendering engine such as [PixiJS](https://www.pixijs.com/) if you want to have performance in your games. You would just have to convert your images into textures.